# Is it possible that a zip entry has no name?

Tags: zip, unzip

When i receive a zip file, is it possible at least in theory, that an entry in the zip file has no name?

I know it is possible that zip entries have duplicate names, or whitespace names. But can the name just be empty while the content is not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, a zip file is allowed by the spec to have a file name length of zero. Depending on your interpretation that either means "no file name" or that the file name is the empty string.

[The spec](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT) explicitly mentions that

> If input came from standard input, the file name length is set to zero.